# Get total network traffic between all nodes in a cluster

Tags: docker, networking, ubuntu-14.04, docker-swarm

I'm working in an docker overlay network with six nodes. I would like to measure the total network traffic between all nodes. I came across iftop but it only counts the bytes between the local machine and each node like:

```
node0(local)<->node1  
node0(local)<->node2
...
but not:
node1<->node2
...
```

I had to install iftop on each node and even then I had to exclude the following connection because it was already counted above.

```
node1(local)<->node0
...
```

Or I had to sum up all total TX or RX values on each node. Additionally I had to start iftop on each node at the same time and pause it when my I see my specified process has finished. Is there an easier way so that I can simply start a record on any host and stop the recording to get the total bytes for this period?

Comment: Did you find any better solution/tool in the meantime?